# How to use Vuetify and css use together in better way?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vuetify.js, tailwind-css

Vuetify alone cant be used for web application development? I **need to add tailwind css or bootstrap with that or not?** Im beginner in this field kindly help to learn veutify. **Ik css and veuityf** but Idk **how to use direct classes in veutify and idk about tcss use in veutify**. Plz guide wiht a road map. TY

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Vuetify is a standalone UI component library with its own default opinionated styling but can also be customized and themed.  It does not *require* anything else like tailwind or bootstrap, but you can use all or none of those libraries depending on your specific application requirements.  If you don't know how to use Vuetify, try reading through all the documentation and maybe find online tutorials. If you have any technical questions on how to do a specific task come back here and ask.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.